# How to get value of Pointer from callback (DLL) function argument in Java using JNA?

Tags: java, dll, jna

I am trying to access image data from scanner hardware. The provided DLL has the following callback function:

[image: callback function registration]

[image: callback function structure]

My Java implementation (using JNA) is as given below:

1. Import Lib

```
    public interface DllReader extends Library {
    
        public Boolean voRegisterImageCallback(ImageCallBack callback, 
       PointerByReference parameter);
    
        public DllReader INSTANCE = Native.load("VideoOCR.dll", 
    DllReader.class);
    
    }
```

2. callback interface:

```
    public interface ImageCallBack extends 
      StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback {
     void imageCallBack(PointerByReference reference, int imageType, 
      Pointer hBitMap);
    }
```

3. Callback impl:

   ```
   public class ImageCallBackImpl implements ImageCallBack{

       @Override
       public void imageCallBack(PointerByReference reference, int 
       imageType, Pointer hBitMap) {
           System.out.println("image data");

           // How to read data on event trigger

       }
   }
   ```

How can I read data from hBitMap pointer?

Comment: Note that given the callback is declared with `_stdcall`, make sure you use `StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback` instead of `Callback`.

Comment: I have edited the question. Can u  help with getting data now. as it gives "Invalid memory access" while doing System.out.println(hBitMap.getByte(0));

Comment: Invalid memory access may be associated with the `Pointer` in the calling function becoming unreachable and getting GC'd.  Use a reachability fence to preserve the pointer. As for using the hbitmap, looks like `GetObject()` shows up everywhere I'm looking, hopefully that moves you forward.